# Some libs are mssing while installing ChromeDriver

Tags: apt, updates, google-chrome

This is the error what I'm getting . Please provide your help on this

Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 udev amd64 245.4-4ubuntu3.18 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80] Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libu2f-udev all 1.1.10-1 [6108 B] Fetched 93.9 MB in 1s (92.3 MB/s) E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/udev_245.4-4ubuntu3.18_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]

Comment: Update your software lists; as they're outdated (ie. run `sudo apt update`).  The correct package is https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/udev  (`245.4-4ubuntu3.19` not the 3.18 you appear to be trying to download/use due to your outdated software lists)

Comment: sudo apt update is not working. Is there any way to add the above mentioned version to source list ?

Comment: Your issue is caused by `sudo apt update` not being run OR not working.  Once you fix whatever issue is there, the issue in this question will disappear instantly.  We can only answer what you provide; this question exists only because you've not run `sudo apt update` successfully in some time (`Thu, 08 Sep 2022 10:58:15 +0100`) being the date from the package in my first comment, but you may not have run it from before that date too.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo apt update
```

and try again.